# Need to select records based upon return from a select in multiple columns using 'like'

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm ok with T-SQL, but I'm struggling here to get a solution to my problem here.

I have a lookup table that depending upon a search criteria can have one or more results.
e.g. where in this case Wimpole is the search value:

```
select Location from L_Locations
where L_Locations.LocationID in
(
    select LocationID from [B_LocationsToMany
    where [B_LocationsToMany].NormalizedLocationID in
    (
        select [B_LocationsToMany].NormalizedLocationID 
        from [B_LocationsToMany] join L_Locations on [B_LocationsToMany].LocationID =     L_Locations.LocationID
        where L_Locations.Location like '%Wimpole%'
)
```

This returns a list like:

```
Wimpole
Wimpole Farm
Wimpole Hall
Wimpole Hole Fm
Wimpole land
Wimpole Lodge 
Wratworth & Wimpole
```

I need to search through multiple fields in another table and return results where any of these fields contain any of the above values. The operator for each field will need to be of a type 'LIKE' since each field can can have from 0 to 2000 characters (i.e. a lot of words).

A starting point would be appreciated.

Ok, thanks to Sam a slight adjustment to his suggestion and I got it working

```
Select * 
    from CommonDocumentData
    where Location in
    (
        SELECT cdd.Location FROM L_Locations AS cdd
        JOIN
        (
            select Location from L_Locations
            where L_Locations.LocationID in
            (

            select LocationID from [B_LocationsToMany]
            where [B_LocationsToMany].NormalizedLocationID in
            (
                select [B_LocationsToMany].NormalizedLocationID 
                from [B_LocationsToMany] join L_Locations on [B_LocationsToMany].LocationID = L_Locations.LocationID
                where L_Locations.Location like '%Wimpole%'
            )
        )) as SearchResults

        ON CommonDocumentData.Description LIKE '%' + SearchResults.location + '%'
    )
```

Comment: Looks like it's going to have to be dynamic SQL?

Comment: Are these `multiple fields` a fixed set?  I also am not sure I see the benefit to using a lookup table, if you're using `LIKE` everywhere.  Whay can't you just use `where <column in main table> like '%Wimpole%'`?

Comment: it can be done with a single query but it's gonna be huge.

Comment: I have to use the look-up table as there are many spellings for Wimpole in historical records and it is used with a bridging table to normalize the name, so searching for Wimpole will also look foar all the alternative spellings, similarly, searching using any of these alternatives will also search for the alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your query should be something like this.

```
 Select * 
    from secondtable
    where ID in (SELECT ID
        FROM secondtable
        JOIN (select Location from L_Locations
    where L_Locations.LocationID in
    (
        select LocationID from [B_LocationsToMany
        where [B_LocationsToMany].NormalizedLocationID in
        (
            select [B_LocationsToMany].NormalizedLocationID 
            from [B_LocationsToMany] join L_Locations on [B_LocationsToMany].LocationID =     L_Locations.LocationID
            where L_Locations.Location like '%Wimpole%'
    )
    ) as SearchResults
        ON secondtable.location LIKE '% ' + SearchResults.location + ' %'
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    (SELECT 
        b.LocationID, b.NormalizedLocationID, Location
    FROM 
        B_LocationsToMany b INNER JOIN 
        L_Locations l ON 
        b.LocationID = l.LocationID INNER JOIN
        L_Locations s ON
        l.locationid = s.locationid
    WHERE 
        L.Location LIKE '%Wimpole%') l INNER JOIN
    TABLE t ON
    l.? = t.?
WHERE
    t.col1 = Location OR
    t.col2 = Location ...
```